# Fill datacombo without to use ADO visual basic 6 access

Tags: vb6

I need to fill a datacombo without to use ADO. I try to do it but a error is triggered.

```
Private rs As Recordset
Private base As Database


Private Sub Form_Load()
  Set base = OpenDatabase("C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\nwind.MDB")
  Set rs = base.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM  Pedidos", dbOpenDynaset)
  'Control Datacombo
    '----------------
    Set DataCombo1.RowSource = rs
    ' campo a mostrar en el datacombo
    DataCombo1.ListField = "FechaPedido"
    DataCombo1.DataField = "FechaPedido"
    Set DataCombo1.DataSource = rs

End Sub
```

Errors

Here is the error
 Set DataCombo1.RowSource = rs  #the types don't match

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use the crusty old DBCombo instead then you need to get rid of the even crustier old DAO you are using.  Those only exist in VB6 to make it easier to do the initial port of an old VB5 program forward into VB6 and have been deprecated since 1998.

A DataCombo can't be bound to what DAO calls a "Recordset."  These are databound ADO controls.

Answer (score 0):

While what Bob77 says is true, you can also easily fill an ordinary ComboBox (not a DataCombo box) "by hand".  Just iterate through your recordset, using AddItem to add values to it as you go.  Put this in a Sub of its own, and call it when needed.  (You'll also have to empty it first if you are changing the values.)

```
Do Until rs.EOF
    cmbMyComboBox.AddItem rs("MyBoxValue")
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

There are more things that you can do.  For example, you can use the .ItemData property of each row to tag it with an integer, which can be the key from your database if you haven't made it something other than an integer.  That way, when a user selects one, you'll have the key for the selected item.

Personally, I never used the DataCombo box or any other form of data binding in VB6 or previous versions, as I found data binding to be much less reliable than doing it myself.  (That has changed with .Net.)  I've always used this technique.